# R: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA, as.integer()

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to create a column (b in the example) that returns the amount of views(a in the example), per title. 
In the Environment it shows 'int' in front of the numbers.

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- as.integer(dataset$a)
b <- dataset %>% group_by(title) %>% mean(a)
View(b)
```

After running the code it gives the following error:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(., a) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Does any of you know how I can solve the error?

Comment: try %>% summarise(mean_a = mean(a)) instead of mean(a)

Comment: Try this - `library(tidyverse)
dataset$a <- as.integer(dataset$a)
b <- dataset %>% group_by(title) %>% mean(a)
View(b)`

Comment: If you have NA's in you a column this mean calculation will return NA as result. Try *mean(na.omit(x))*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are not using the right approach, try this instead:

```
b <- dataset %>% group_by(title) %>% mean(as.integer(a), na.rm=T)
View(b)
```

My point is your line   where you are converting **a** doesn't impact you dataset but another object **a**. But in your ***mean*** function your are using **a** from your dataset.

Hope it helps